# Is there a way to include multiple words in a name, without having to display single quotes around each name or at least hide them?

Tags: r

Hi I have the variable which includes spaces between characters `D B` <- c("a", "b", "c"). Is there a way to include multiple words in a name, without having to display single quotes around each name? Or at least eliminate or hide the quotes after creating the variable? The final result is used for a shiny app and is annoying to have `` around the D B.

Comment: why not just D_B?

Comment: Based on the case that Im working this may be my final choice but I would like to avoid it.

Comment: Been a while since using shiny, but it there some way to use something like, `D_SPACE_B` then get some kind of javascript to modify the page source in real time to replace the `_SPACE_` with a space? A bit hackerish though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot include spaces in an identifier. You can include only letters, numbers, dots (as in the full stop character `.`), and underlines in identifiers. Anything else (including spaces) is not valid. The way to avoid the quotes is to not use spaces in your variable names, perhaps by using dots or underlines instead.

See the documentation for [make.names()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html).

Comment: I strongly object using a full stop in variable names. In OOP-languages the `.` is used to call object methods/attributes for e.g.. Use and learn something that works with "all" programming languages.

Comment: @AndreElrico: Cannot is correct. This is why quotation marks are needed - because it is not a valid identifier. And you should use the capabilities and conventions of the language you are working in; importing them from other languages is not good practice.